# Is CFStringTokenizer supposed to ignore punctuation and symbols?

Tags: objective-c, swift, tokenize

I'm just learning Swift and playing around with CFStringTokenizer and I have noticed that when the string is tokenized punctuation and symbols are ignored. I'm not too familiar with the topic of Tokenization, but I want to better understand how the tokenizer works if ever I have need to do more complex tokenization that requires me to find things such as "!" or "+". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So my questions are:

- Is the ignoring of symbols and punctuation as tokens expected behaviour?
- Is there a way to get CFStringTokenizer to treat a symbol as a token or to keep a symbol as part of a token? i.e. "+", "-3" or "world!"
- Can someone also explain how the CFStringTokenizerTokenType works for testing the type of token?

Here is a playground I've been working with:

```
import Cocoa

var str = "I have 2 pairs of pants + five shirts, but threw out 3 socks with holes! 2+5-3"
var tokens: [(token: String, range: CFRange, type: CFStringTokenizerTokenType)] = []
var strLen = countElements(str)
var strRng = CFRangeMake(0, strLen)
var flag = UInt(kCFStringTokenizerUnitWord)
var locale = CFLocaleCopyCurrent()

var tknizr = CFStringTokenizerCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, str, strRng, flag, locale)
var tknType = CFStringTokenizerAdvanceToNextToken(tknizr)


do {
    var tRng = CFStringTokenizerGetCurrentTokenRange(tknizr)

    var from = advance(str.startIndex, tRng.location)
    var to = advance(from, tRng.length)
    var substrRng = Range<String.Index>(start: from, end: to)
    var substr = str.substringWithRange(substrRng)

    println("String: \(substr)")
    println("Token Type: \(tknType.rawValue)\n")

    tokens += [(substr, tRng, tknType)]

    tknType = CFStringTokenizerAdvanceToNextToken(tknizr)
} while tknType.rawValue != 0
```

--UPDATE--

I added the objective-c tag because this applies to obj-c as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so after much looking around, I found some answers.

> Is the ignoring of symbols and punctuation as tokens expected behaviour?

Yes, `kCFStringTokenizerUnitWord` will only pull out words as tokens, so it is expected behaviour. I was using the wrong options for CFStringTokenizer.

> Is there a way to get CFStringTokenizer to treat a symbol as a token or to keep a symbol as part of a token? i.e. "+", "-3" or "world!"

I should have been using `kCFStringTokenizerUnitWordBoundary` instead. It will capture symbols as tokens. The downside to that is that spaces are also captured as tokens, but easily ignored with a bit of extra logic.

> Can someone also explain how the CFStringTokenizerTokenType works for testing the type of token?

<shakeshead>Feeling like a total newb here, they are bitmasks, not literal values.</shakeshead> Therefore, my testing of the raw values with logical operators was the wrong approach. Bitwise operators are the correct way to test for token types.